# I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my C# code

Tags: c#

I am attempting to make a simple program that counts up one each time I press spacebar. I am very very new to writing software and most of this is completely foreign to me, so if you understand how I am thinking incorrectly I will welcome your insight!

```
using System;

namespace Counter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tap = 0;

            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
                tap++;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried. The console shows (0) and then closes when I press spacebar. I don't know how to stop it from closing the console, it's as if all it has in the code body is a variable and "Console.WriteLine()".

Comment: I think your program does exactly the opposite of what you want, it counts each time you press anything different from space bar, try == instead of !=.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, that mostly fixed it! Not, though, it closes after providing a count. How do I make it loop? I came to C# after a week of learning VBA, but the commands I learned aren't the same.

Comment: Whenever I am ready to exit the program. This is actually a test run for an arduino device I'm making for a board game. I just want it to sit there and maintain various input counts until I'm ready to turn it off. I've been researching how to answer my own question for hours now but I'm not understanding things like "method" and "standard input stream" and the other jargon you programmers are accustomed to, so I'm asking for explicit help to possibly learn some of that jargon along the way.

Comment: Method - code that "does something" as opposed to the only other kind of code - code that declares data storage. "Doing something" essentially is either storing,reading or transforming data. Your Main is a method; it "does stuff". If your Program class had something like `public string Name;` that's a line of code that declares data storage, but it doesn't specifically "do something" in and of itself

Comment: Methods can also contain lines of code that declare storage, and in an amusing twist it's possible to declare data storage that holds a method as if it were data, but we'll get to that later

Comment: If a class is a recipe, then the data is like the ingredients and the methods deceive the process of making the cake/whatever

Comment: Standard input - a stream of data into your program from the command window; usually tied to the keyboard but doesn't have to be. ReadKey and ReadLine read from it so you can get the data that the puts into the stream (by hammering on the keyboard) into your program

Comment: Okay, I think I understand those particular terms better now. Thanks for the responses, I feel very swamped right now. I've since changed my approach, having discovered the 'switch' expression, and I have keys to count down as well as reset the count to zero. Currently trying to find out how to keep the displayed numbers on one line.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
        var tap = 0;

        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
        {
            tap++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Key is not Spacebar, tap count = {tap}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You just press spacebar, now press enter to exit this console app");
        Console.ReadLine();//press enter to exit
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int tap = 0;

    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
    {
        tap++;
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed 'Spacebar' " + tap + "-time(s) so far.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("You didn't press 'Spacebar' this time!");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait 3 seconds so you actually have the chance to read the text in the console
}
```

Event though I would recommend something like this instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int tap = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if(Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
        {
            tap++;
            Console.WriteLine("You pressed 'Spacebar' " + tap + "-time(s) so far.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't press 'Spacebar' this time!");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // wait 3 seconds so you actually have the chance to read the text in the console
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is how to resolve a question in stackoverflow, but the answer was to make an if/elseif loop where Spacebar was an input that was counted and Enter was a Boolean value that closed the program when triggered to True.

```
{
        var tap = 0;
        bool quit = false;

        while (quit == false)
        {

            if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                tap++;
                Console.WriteLine(tap);
            }
            else if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

With the ElseIf I was able to count every trigger of Spacebar, whereas previously I had that statement within the If loop and it waited on the next keypress to see whether it was the Enter key or not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Watch out: if the first key is not the "space", then it will wait *again* to see if the *next* key is "enter"

Comment: I've since changed the approach (using a switch expression now), however when I used that ElseIf expression it did not seem to skip a keypress while waiting for the "Enter" key.